# Кликабельный текстовый канал в личных сообщениях Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord

Есть такой бот MEE6, когда он пишет мне в ЛС, я могу нажать на #правила и меня перекинет на текстовый канал. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я отправляю просто #правила оно не становиться кликабельным.

```
member.send("#:no_entry:правила", );
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй ID канала `member.send("<#PLACEYOURIDHERE>")`